# S3 www to non-www redirect appends /index.html to the URL

Tags: amazon-s3, redirect, single-page-application, amazon-cloudfront

Assuming my domain is `example.com`, I have setup www to non-www redirects using two S3 buckets, two CloudFront distributions as per [this](https://simonecarletti.com/blog/2016/08/redirect-domain-http-https-www-cloudfront/) blog post and setup a redirect in the www bucket pointing to `example.com`.

This works well, but it actually redirects to `example.com/index.html`. Is it possible to redirect it just to `example.com`?

Comment: have you found the reason or solution?

Answer (score 0):

Is there anything in your distribution's configuration that has `index.html`? I can't say why you are seeing the redirect with index.html appended, but a simpler way to do this—without two buckets, and to have more control over the redirect—is to use CloudFront Functions (available in the **Functions** section of the CloudFront console). Here is an example:

```
    function handler(event) {
        var request = event.request;
        var host = request.headers.host.value;

        if (host === 'www.example.com') {    
            var response = {
                statusCode: 301,
                statusDescription: 'Moved Permanently',
                headers: { 
                    'location': { 'value': `https://example.com${request.uri}` } 
                }
            };

            return response;
        }

        return request;
    }
```

You would set this as a viewer-request function, and attach it to the cache behavior(s). With this setup, you would only need to have a single distributions with both example.com and [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) set as alternate domain names.

If you  need to set `index.html` as your root object, you can also do that in the function when the  host is not [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) by modifying the `request.uri` - this way if you have any reference to `index.html` in your distribution you could move it all to this function. Here is an example function that demonstrates how to rewrite the URI before the request is sent to S3 (ensuring the external-facing URL is unchanged):
https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-cloudfront-functions/tree/main/url-rewrite-single-page-apps

Comment: I would prefer not to incur extra cost and go by without a CloudFront function. In this case, I had previously had the `defaultRootObject` set to `index.html` in the CloudFront distribution, I then removed it but the behaviour still persists. Would it likely be because of that?

Answer (score 0):

Check that your www distribution does not have "Default root object" value of `index.html`.
Making it blank fixed the same issue for me.